# How to update part of a MongoDb document by using the child documents MongoId using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a Mongo document as presented below. Using PHP I need to update the password of an account, I could access it by either email or id.

I thought the following code will bring focus to the part of the document when executing an update:

```
$criteria = array("accounts.email" => $emailAddress);
$document = array(
    '$set' => array(
        "accounts.password" => $newPassword
     )
);
```

But when doing an update nothing gets updated. Any idea how I could update the password by only providing the email address or id?

```
{
"accounts": [
    {
      "id": ObjectId("5266cf3c9b7e7a292b000002"),
      "main": true,
      "username": "username_a",
      "password": "password_a",
      "email": "a@a.com"
    },
    {
      "id": ObjectId("5266cf3c9b7e7a292b000004"),
      "main": true,
      "username": "username_a",
      "password": "password_b",
      "email": "b@b.com"
    }
  ],
  "active": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [positional $ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

```
$criteria = array("accounts.email" => $emailAddress);
$document = array(
    '$set' => array(
        'accounts.$.password' => $newPassword
     )
);

$collection->update($criteria, $document);
```

Comment: Hi Bjori, I've tried your suggestion but no luck. The data in the document stays unchanged, strangely enough no error is returned either. Have any clue?

Comment: I managed to get an error message out of the system: "Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array".

Comment: The mistake was obvious mine, a typo.

The positional $ operator was what I needed.